# Getting an empty list when trying to extract data from an attribute using XPath query

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have opened [this link](https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/reliance-industries-ltd/reliance/500325/corp-announements/) in scrapy shell. I used the below XPath code to find value for href attribute    `response.xpath('//a[@class="tablebluelink"]/@href').extract()`

It returns me an empty list []

I have tried to find relevant API calls inside Network settings to no avail.

Comment: If I search the filename of one of the PDF files in the Network tab, it finds a match in https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/AnnGetData/w?strCat=-1&strPrevDate=20200207&strScrip=500325&strSearch=A&strToDate=20200507&strType=C

Comment: The site uses dynamic rendering. You can notice it if you disable Javascript. You'll have to use Selenium (or other) to fetch all urls of the PDF documents.

Comment: @Gallaecio Thanks! Been on it for the last 2 days and your trick didn't cross my mind.

Comment: @E.Wiest I was trying it in scrapy. Do you think scrapy + splash will do a similar job as selenium? Thanks.

Comment: I've never used it but it should. Keep us informed. Downloading and extracting the urls from the json as suggested by @Gallaecio is probably faster though.